# Quartz and MySQL 6.9.9

Tags: mysql, asp.net, quartz.net

I am running a .NET web application with MySQL 6.9.9, and I'm trying to integrate Quartz into my project.
I'm running into a problem with connecting Quartz to my database. It seems that the providers available for MySQL on Quartz only go up to 6.9.5, so my config file looks something like this:

```
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Server=localhost; Port=3306;Database=cart_default; Uid=xxxxxxx; Pwd=xxxxxxxx;" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="MySql-695" />
```

I got this to work by downloading and installing the MySQLData.dll version 6.9.5, but I can't do that for my webserver, due to access to it.

The Quartz documentation says:

> You can and should use latest version of driver if newer is available, just create an assembly binding redirect

Which I am doing in my web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.8.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

And that doesn't seem to help either.

Lastly, I see in the source code for Quartz where they are setting the properties of the different providers here: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Impl/AdoJobStore/Common/dbproviders.properties
And I see the one for Mysql 695. If there was a way I can modify this file for my version, or somehow modify the properties and add new one `quartz.dbprovider` for `MySQL-699` I feel that would make this work.

I'm looking for any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all that was needed was the assembly redirect, due to changes and branches, the user who had this issue didn't have the updated web.config with the assembly redirect.